# MYSQL - using where and filesort

Tags: mysql, indexing

Hello this query is producing this explain which is odd considering I have a index set up for both the columns

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'vtr_video_transactions', 'ALL', 'user_standard,user_date', NULL, NULL, NULL, '5', 'Using where; Using filesort'

CREATE TABLE `vtr_video_transactions` (
  `vtr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vtr_transaction_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `vtr_user_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `vtr_standards_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `vtr_video_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vtr_id`),
  KEY `user_standard` (`vtr_user_id`,`vtr_standards_id`),
  KEY `user_date` (`vtr_user_id`,`vtr_video_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

See user_date for the index. I have it set to DESC on MYSQL Workbench. But I get filesort with the explain. Not sure why. Cheers

Data for table

```
LOCK TABLES `vtr_video_transactions` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `vtr_video_transactions` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `vtr_video_transactions` VALUES (1,1,1,2,'2015-09-05 17:18:59'),(2,2,1,3,'2015-08-27 19:04:12'),(3,2,1,4,'2015-08-27 18:55:53'),(4,10,1,119,'2015-08-27 19:04:12'),(5,11,1,10,'2015-08-27 19:04:12');
```

Comment: What's the number of records your table have?

Comment: what query? Thx for the headers for the explain output !

Comment: There are 5 rows overall.

Comment: well that is why. It is slower to use the index, so the db engine is doing you a favor.

Comment: Yeah, probably that's why it's doing a file sort. Due less rows and avoiding index key lookups.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that. So with enough rows it should change the explain

Comment: Yes, even for 1K rows it still may choose to do file sort cause 1K as well is less.

Comment: show us the query. I can jam in random rows, and get the explain to show something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the manual page [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.